# Cannot loop over all the matrix elements

Tags: c, loops, matrix

I am trying to create a data structure to store a matrix and write a routine to generate a square matrix of random numbers.

Here is my code. I am strangely getting only 2 float numbers as output. I am doing all this to implement strassen matrix multiplication, which is why I added `rs, re, cs, ce` to struct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h>   

typedef struct _matrix {
    int rs;
    int re;
    int cs;
    int ce;
    float a[100][100];
}matrix;

void display(matrix m)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i=m.rs ; i<=m.re ; i++) {
        for (j=m.cs ; j<=m.ce ; j++) 
            printf("%f", m.a[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

    return;
}

matrix random_matrix(int n)
{
    matrix random;   
    random.cs = random.rs = 0;
    random.rs = random.re = n -1;

    int i, j;   

    for(i=0; i < n; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
            random.a[i][j] = rand();
    }

    return random;       
}

int main(void)
{ 
    matrix m1 = random_matrix(3);
    matrix m2 = random_matrix(3);  
    display(m1); 
    display(m2);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: call `srand(time(NULL));` in `main()` once.

Comment: random number generation is not my problem. Major issue with my code is i am only getting 2 floats as output insterd of getting 3x3 matrices. I dont get where i messed up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, to fit the logic, in your code, in `random_matrix()` function,

```
   random.rs = random.re = n -1;
```

should be

```
  random.ce = random.re = n -1;
```

Otherwise, in `display()`, `for (i=m.rs ; i<=m.re ; i++)` does not make sense.

That said, to see the random number generator, you can call `srand(time(NULL));` in `main()`, before the call to the matrix generation functions.

Comment: A simple typo: just beat me.

Comment: @emperorspride188 you really must learn some basic debugging, such as examining the values of your control variables.

Comment: @WeatherVane :). sometimes you just need an extra pair of eyes to catch these sort of errors. :)